# Flutter : Edit profile returns 401 'Unauthenticated' but works in POSTMAN

Tags: http, flutter, dart

i was trying to edit my user's profile with flutter and laravel based on this  [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfMWAfyzVcM) . My register and login works fine. However, when i try to edit it always return this error.

Here are some of my codes;

**api.dart**

```
class CallApi {
final String _url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/';
var token ;

postData(data, apiUrl) async {
var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
print(fullUrl);
return await http.post(
    fullUrl,
    body: jsonEncode(data),
    headers: _setHeaders());
}

editData(data, apiUrl) async {

var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
return await http.post(
    fullUrl,
    body: jsonEncode(data),
    headers: _setTokenHeaders())
    .then((response) {
  print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body : ${response.body}');
});
 }

getData(apiUrl) async {
var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
return await http.get(fullUrl, headers: _setHeaders());
 }

_setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

_getToken() async {
SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var token = localStorage.getString('token');
return '?token=$token';
 }

_setTokenHeaders() =>
  {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $_getToken()',
  };


}
```

**Handle update function**

```
void _handleUpdate() async {
setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});



var data = {
  'residency': locationController.text,
  'spouse': spouseController.text,
  'occupation': occupationController.text,
 };

var res = await CallApi().postData(data, 'profile');
 // i've tried both postData and editData which returns the same error
var body = json.decode(res.body); 
print(body);
/*if (body['status'] == true) {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  localStorage.setString('user_details', json.encode(body['token']));

  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Profile.tag);
}*/
}
```

**Logcat**

```
I/flutter ( 2390): {message: Unauthenticated.}
```

The api works properly through postman and i have checked the url and parameters which i am entering in the post request and they are the same as that of postman but still i keep getting the error.

Whats working on POSTMAN

- Register
- Login
- Logout
- Update

On flutter App

- Register
- Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only return the `token` only. No need to return string query.

```
_getToken() async {
    ...
    return token;
};
```

Also, remove the `_getToken()` from your `fullUrl` variable. You need to send the token by headers, not by query parameters.

**EDITED**

Your `postData()` function should be using `_setTokenHeaders()` in the headers instead.

Comment: unfortunately, it returns 404 NotFoundHttpException. Does this mean something is wrong with my API route in laravel?

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::post('/profile', 'API\UserController@updateProfile');

Comment: @mirulmadridista No need to include ```await _getToken();``` in the ```fullUrl``` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApiResponse {
  final bool isSuccessful;
  final dynamic data; // Updated the type to dynamic
  final String? error;
  final String? message;

  ApiResponse({
    required this.isSuccessful,
    this.data,
    this.error,
    this.message,
  });
}

//structure depends on your API response

// your update
  Future<ApiResponse> updateData(
    String firstthing,
    String secondthing,
    String token,
  ) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/route');

    // Print the headers before making the API request.
    final headers = {
      ..._headers,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
    print('Headers: $headers');

    final body = {
      'firstthing': firstthing,
      'secondthing': secondthing,
    };
    print('Body: $body');

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: json.encode(body),
    );

    // Print the final response.
    print('Final Response: ${response.body}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      final isSuccessful = responseData['isSuccessful'] ?? false;
      return ApiResponse(
        isSuccessful: isSuccessful,
        data: responseData['data'],
        message: responseData['message'],
      );
    } else {
      final errorBody = json.decode(response.body);
      final isSuccessful = errorBody['isSuccessful'] ?? false;
      return ApiResponse(
        isSuccessful: isSuccessful,
        error: errorBody['error'],
        message: errorBody['message'],
      );
    }
  }
```

//Follow the steps to acquire a successfull api call